Can you somehow restrict any installed app with your own app?
Basically I want to create an app where you can select any of your installed apps and then restrict/unrestrict them. I have a great idea for an app, but need the user to be able to restrict an installed app with my own app for it to work.
I tried working with screen time restrictions but couldn't get it to work somehow. Im doing this on IOS 17 Xcode. Also im pretty new to programming so I dont know a lot of stuff. I especially lack a lot of knowledge in screen time of iOS 17.

Restricted on same device, or multiple (other) devices?

on the same device

Unfortunately for your case you can't restrict or interact with another app on the device that you didn't write and explicitly allow your new app to access.


I'm afraid Apple does not provide API to get any installed apps (by security reasons)
For implementing the application restrict/unrestrict you need to build your own VPN. I can suggest checkout UI/UX for an application like "Freedoom" - they just predict what app to allow and what app to restrict (using their own VPN)
Apple gets this statistic about usage by using their private API, but they can share this data with you. I can suggest to check out this WWDC video What's new in Screen Time API


Apple does provide a mechanism where a limited number of apps can exclusively share information amongst themselves: "App Groups".
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups
Using this, they can pass information to each other via UserDefaults
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1409957-init
or shared files via "shared containers".
With this, it seems like you could make these related apps set and read some limitations via config file.

Oh, okay, I'll just clarify here... I assumed you meant any locally installed apps that you wrote. App's on iOS are isolated from each other at many levels (bundles, sandbox, etc.) They can't tell teach other what to do. (Let's assume that "custom" URLs are not viable).

Thanks! However this means that how I was intending to limit the apps wouldnt work, is that right?

Right. Like if you have two apps like: child.app and parent.app, you can make them order each other around. But you can't really do anything to mess with Twitter's app.
